# How do I configure gerrit's plugin "reviewers"?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have never used gerrit with plugins so I am a little bit lost.
I have cloned the plugin and I have the folder with the folders .git, lib. src and tools. 
Let's say I want to implement it in a project that I have already cloned. What do I do with the reviewers folder? Where do I have to place it? How will it work?

Thanks a lot. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to clone the plugin, you can download it from GerritForge:

1. Go to https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/
2. Choose the tab Plugins-2.x according with your Gerrit version
3. Search for plugin-reviewers-*
4. Download the reviewers.jar file

Then you need to install the plugin in the Gerrit server. You need to be a Gerrit admin to do that.

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html).

Finally, you need to configure the plugin.

See more info [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/reviewers/+/refs/heads/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot!